# "Tired of" or "tired from"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, terminology, commas, orthography

Which is correct to say... are you not tired **of** being in pain because of football or are you not tired **from** being in pain because of football?

Comment: The first could mean that you're fed up with (annoyed with) being in pain, while the second could mean that you're exhausted because of the pain.

Comment: *Prepositions with tired* - 
• If you are tired of doing something, you do not want to do it anymore because it has started to annoy or bore you. 
I’m tired of explaining it.
*✗Don’t say: I’m tired from explaining it.*
• If you are tired from doing something, you feel tired because you have used a lot of effort:
He was tired from walking all day.
*✗Don’t say: He was tired of walking all day.* https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tired

Comment: Thank you very much